# What is the standard naming to the POJOs inside a POJO?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, pojo

Say I have a bigger POJO, which consists of some other POJOs. What is the standard naming to these other POJOs within the bigger POJO? Most generally, I think we can call them *child POJO* or *sub-POJO*? But what is the standard naming? Like node? Element? Component? Section?